# Android: Send serialized objects interspersed with parameters to server

Tags: android, serialization, stream

**Situation:** : I must either send a parameter to the server, or a serialized object. It can be in any random order.

**What I've done:** As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190296/android-2-threads-listening-on-the-same-socket), I developed a protocol to let the server know what I'm sending just before I actually send it. If its any string, it just goes via PrintWriter.println().

But just before sending a serialized object via ObjectInputStream, I send a PrintWriter.println("O"). So the server knows it must expect a serialized object next.

**Problem:** I'm getting the StreamCorruptedException, even though I'm using only one instance of ObjectInputStream at the client throughout the socket's life. Should anything be done at the Server end ?

----------------------- EDITED BELOW ---------------------

Client End:

```
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(thisSocket.getOutputStream())),
                true);

                if (!sent){
                    out.println("Dummy");
                    sent = true;
                }

                objectOutputStream.flush();
                objectOutputStream.reset();

                out.println("#SerialO#"); //This param signals the server
                                          //that an object will be sent next.

                if(((calcSum) this.obj).getRemotable()){
                    /*objectOutputStream.flush();
                    objectOutputStream.reset();*/

                        Log.i("ENDPOINT", "Sending Serialized data ...");
                        objectOutputStream.writeObject(this.obj);
                        objectOutputStream.flush();
                        objectOutputStream.reset();

                        // Get the byte array
                        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                }
```

Server End:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try{
                    this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                    // NOW DECLARED AND USED IN UpdateUIThread
                    //PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                    if(!sent)
                    {
                        flg = this.input.readLine().toString();
                        Log.i("SERVER","SERVER Received False flg as "+flg);
                        sent = true;
                    }
                    else{

                    flg = this.input.readLine().toString();

                    System.out.println("SERVER Received flg as "+flg);

                    if(flg.contains("#SerialO#")){  //Be prepared to
                                              // receive a serilized obj from client

                        //Log.d("SERVER","Received an object");
                        CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(this.clientSocket,it);
                        new Thread(commThread).start();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Log.d("SERVER","Received a parameter "+flg);
                        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
                        executor.execute(new updateUIThread(this.clientSocket,flg));
                    }
                  }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("SERVER", "Creation went bad -- "+e.toString());
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d("CLIENT TAG", "Creation went bad -- "+e.toString());  
                }
            }
        }


...

public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket, Intent it) {

            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {

                Log.d("SERVER","Inside Server's Comm Thread");

                if (mInput==null){
                    Log.i("SERVER","Receiving very first serialized obj");
                    mOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                    System.out.println("Inside Server's Comm Thread 2 ");

// EXCEPTION OCCURS IN THE LINE BELOW.
                    mInput = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                }
```

Comment: Could you post the code where the exception occurs?

Comment: Hi Niek. I just edited the question with the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix streams and readers/writers on the same socket if any of them is buffered. In this situation I would use the object stream for everything.

Comment: Hi EJP. Instead of buffered writer/reader and BufferedInputStream, will it work by plain writer/reader and InputStream ? Or do I necessarily have to use ObjectInputStream for everything ?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, EJP. I send a boolean via ObjectOutputStream before I am to send a serialized object or not. This works in case of a serialized object. But when I send a string, and try to receive it at the server using readFully(), it just hangs at that line.

Comment: Send a string how? If it's what you wrote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21380204/207421), it's a pointless mess. Forget it. I would send everything as objects, or, if you must, send the string a with writeUTF() and read them with readUTF(). If you're sending objects you don't need a protocol telling you what the next object is. Its type tells you that: use 'instanceof'.

Comment: Hey EJP, I'm using the combo of writeUTF() and readUTF() as suggested by David. I've posted details of the results in that post.