# Android: ObjectInputSteam.readFully() gets Stuck

Tags: android, sockets, objectinputstream

**Situation** : I send a boolean variable via `ObjectOutputStream` from a client to a server. Thereafter, I immediately send a string data via `writeChars()` function. The server receives the boolean via `readBoolean()` and spawns a thread accordingly. It reads the string using `readFully(bytes[])`.

**Problem** : Server hangs at the line `ObjectInputStream.readFully(bytes[])`.

Should I just increase the byte size, or is the whole approach wrong ?

Comment: `readFully(bytes[])` wants to read as many bytes as there are in the `byte` array you pass it. Do you know exactly how many `byte`s to expect? Is the array sized correctly?

Comment: Hi David. The string I send is just : 8~9~^. And the byte array size is 500. Should it be the exact size ? How to make it read variable string sizes ? (if its possible).

Answer (score 1):

If this is a `String` and you are using `ObjectOutputStream` you should just call `writeUTF()` to write it and `readUTF()` to read it. This method actually first writes the number of bytes to the stream and then the bytes. On the receiving end, it reads the number of bytes and then knows how many bytes to expect.

Comment: David, thanks for the suggestion. I think I just missed to mention the flow of my server code. A thread reads a boolean from the objectInputStream and spawns another thread to read the string (I now put UTF there). Now its listening to the readUTF, and in the parent thread, its looped back to listen to the next boolean variable. Is this causing the problem ? (BTW, it now hangs at the line readUTF too).

Comment: Certainly it causes the problem. What's the point of the second thread? It is fighting with the original thread for data. Anything could happen. According to your protocol, the original thread has to wait until the string is read before it can sensibly read the next Boolean anyway, so the second thread serves no useful purpose at all. Just read the string in the original thread.

Comment: There is no reason to start multiple threads to read from a single socket.

Comment: EJP & David, I've just done what you said. But it turns out that readUTF() is a blocking call. Exeution just hangs at that line. Tried combinations of flush() and reset() at both client and server, but it still hangs at that line. (It gets pushed only on the next round of writeUTF() -- readUTF() ). I was advised not to use OutputStream() in place of ObjectInputStream, and readLine() is depricated. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I'll try sending an Object with the intended string inside it like EJP suggested in another post.

Comment: OK. That worked. Thank you for your suggestions, David and EJP.